# helm list all installed charts

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

How can I list, show all the charts installed by helm on a K8s? If I run helm in a newly installed Ubuntu I cannot see which repos were used before to install the charts.

Kind of

```
helm show all *
```

Can I somehow export the helm's repository list and history from previously used server to the new ubuntu server? Where does helm keep the which repository installed etc?

Old ubuntu server

```
Helm repo list
NAME            URL
gitlab          https://charts.gitlab.io/
harbor          https://helm.goharbor.io
bitnami         https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
```

The New ubuntu server

```
Helm repo list
NAME            URL
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 44):

> How can I list, show all the charts installed by helm on a K8s?

[`helm list`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_list/) `--all-namespaces`

> Where does helm keep the which repository installed etc?

[By default](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/advanced/#storage-backends) in Secret objects in the same namespace as the release, but this can be changed.

> Can I somehow export the helm's repository list and history

Not really.  You can use [`helm get values`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_get_values/) to get the set of values a particular release was installed with.  I don't believe there's an option to tell you where the chart originally came from.

Rather than trying to export this information from a cluster, a better approach is to make sure you have a copy of the information you need to recreate it in source control.  If the cluster state is small enough, you can try recreating it on a desktop-based Kubernetes installation (Docker Desktop, minikube, kind) for test purposes.  This could be a directory of shell scripts with install commands and matching value YAML files; there are also higher-level tools like [Helmsman](https://github.com/Praqma/helmsman) and [Helmfile](https://github.com/roboll/helmfile) that try to maintain an installation of several charts together.

Comment: +1 thanks helm list --all-namespaces helped but it does not show which repository used for the installed chart.  

```
NAME                       NAMESPACE          REVISION UPDATED                                STATUS   CHART                                   APP VERSION
gitlab-runner              gitlab-runner      1        2020-06-15 22:42:27.743159 +0100 BST   deployed gitlab-runner-0.17.1                    13.0.1

```

Answer (score 16):

```
helm list -A
```

- A is for listing all namespaces

Answer (score 0):

While no guarantee, if you are just researching, you can `helm repo list` too.

Once you have done `helm list ...` you can also `helm search repo <chart>` for your chart name. If it's only available in one repo, you probably have the right one.

Just be aware that it isn't actually asking k8s which repo was used to deploy a given chart; it's just asking where you can find it now.